# Unable to connect to a database on a shared drive - UCanAccess

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I've setup my application to connect to a Access database through UCanAccess however I'm unable to connect to a database that is located on the shared drive. See below for examples.

```
String databasePath = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Desktop/MyDB.accdb"  \\\\ this works
String databasePath = "jdbc:ucanaccess://servername/etc/MyDB.accdb" \\\\ does not work and throws no suitable driver found exception
```

Interesting enough when I map my folder on the shared drive to some letter e.g. P: - it successfully connects.

```
String databasePath = "jdbc:ucanaccess://P:/servername/etc/MyDB.accdb"  \\\\ this works
```

Is it possible to go around this? My users have r/w permissions to the folder but I don't want to map drives on each machine.
Thanks

Comment: When you try //servername the jdbc driver has to handle the smb/cifs protocol of your file server, which he can't. You need the OS to handle the network part of the share. After the share is maped on a drive letter, jdbc tries to access it like a local file, and your os is handling smb/cifs. thats all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply don't have enough forward slashes in your connection URL to represent a UNC path. As you have noted, for a local connection to `C:\Desktop\MyDB.accdb` you can use

```java
String databasePath = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Desktop/MyDB.accdb";
```

Similarly, for a UNC connection to `\\servername\etc\MyDB.accdb` you can use

```java
String databasePath = "jdbc:ucanaccess:////servername/etc/MyDB.accdb";
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I had a peculiar feeling that it was something trivial as a slash. Thanks Gord that solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The database driver can only handle his specified protocolls.
Most of jdbc drivers can only handle the network protocol for his specific database server.

You are using the access jdbc driver which can only handle file access to a given accdb file.

When you try an url like:

> jdbc:ucanaccess://servername/etc/MyDB.accdb

The driver makes a local file access to this path which does not exist localy. 
What you expect is, that the driver would make up a SMB/CIFS connection to your server, which he can't!

You have to map the SMB/CIFS share over your OS on to a local drive letter. Because then the OS is handling the network SMB/CIFS stuff for you. And the JDBC driver can access the file as it would access a local file.