# Connecting UCanAccess to a database on a network share

Tags: java, lan, netbeans-8, ucanaccess

I have to make a LAN-based app, but I'm having trouble with connecting my database to my Java project. When I tried this

```
public static void databaseCon(String connection) {
    try{
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:\\\\KIM-PC\\share\\FPAS.accdb");            
    }
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

the error message that I'm getting is

> no suitable driver found for...

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to a database on a shared drive - UCanAccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814796/unable-to-connect-to-a-database-on-a-shared-drive-ucanaccess)

Comment: Try using forward slashes (/) instead of backslashes (\\) in your connection URL: `jdbc:ucanaccess:////KIM-PC/share/FPAS.accdb`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.. but It didnt work IDK why?

Comment: Try commenting out the `Class.forName` statement. Chances are good that you don't need it.