# Unable to connect from Unix box to Access database on Windows server

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I saw answer mentioned by Gord in

[Unable to connect to a database on a shared drive - UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814796/unable-to-connect-to-a-database-on-a-shared-drive-ucanaccess).

I am able to access my db from Windows to Windows Server where my Access Database file resides.

But when I deploy the same code on Unix, I am not able to access my database. I am using the same URL as proposed by Gord.

My URL is:

```
datasource.crr.url=jdbc:ucanaccess://////abc.dch.com\\der\\Share\\SongUnflaggedTest\\Songs\ Unflagged.accdb;Skipindexes=true;memory=true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Windows, most Linux/Unix environments are unable to directly access a file in a shared folder by simply using its UNC path, e.g.,

```
\\server\share\folder\file.ext
```

Instead, we normally have to tell the Linux/Unix box to `mount` the share at a point on the local filesystem (sort of like assigning a drive letter in Windows), and then use that as the starting point.

For example, if we `mount` the share

```
\\server\share
```

to a mount point on the local filesystem named

```
/mnt/servershare
```

then we can access the file using the path

```
/mnt/servershare/folder/file.ext
```

See [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/562088/323236) for an example.