# Java program cannot access database that resides in NAS storage

Tags: java, datasource

I'm using `Spring` boot to

I have this dataSource:

```
 DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
           dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:ucanaccess://10.221.112.25/ekaa/UCYTesting/E125_DS.accdb;openExlcusive=false;ignorecase=trueB");
      dataSource.setUsername("test");
      dataSource.setPassword("test");
```

However, my code can't connect to this database:
[image]

When I try in file explorer I can access it:
[image]

Note that the database in on a NAS storage server.

Comment: is the filelocation you provided is pointing to the correct place.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this, a problem with slashes for UNC parhname: [Unable to connect to a database on a shared drive - UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814796/unable-to-connect-to-a-database-on-a-shared-drive-ucanaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the JDBC URL, although I am also not 100% sure what it should look like. Try

```
jdbc:ucanaccess:file:///10.221.112.25/ekaa/UCYTesting/E125_DS.accdb;openExlcusive=false;ignorecase=trueB
```

You could also map drive letter N: to that NAS storage, then

```
jdbc:ucanaccess:file:///N:/UCYTesting/E125_DS.accdb;openExlcusive=false;ignorecase=trueB
```

Note: After file the two slashes denote the protocol to use for the connection, the next slash indicates an absolute path. Three slashes are on purpose. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme